# Scrollview shows wrong color when swiping down and using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight

Tags: android, material-design

I've added the latest material design:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

I've set the new `DayNight` theme in my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

I have these colors in my `values-night\colors.xml` and `values\colors.xml`:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
```

I have a ScrollView, but when I swipe down, I see a purple color instead of the colors that match the theme. How can I change this color?

[image]

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_default">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```